# Validate Input of a Form Against Another Collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

I would like to validate the input of a form against the existence of common fields in another collection. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Edit: Added code example and context

I have simply built this as a prototype infrastructure.

Schemas:

```
Transactions.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  key: { // When inserted this need to be an existing key
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000000000,
  },
  employee: { // When inserted this need to be an existing employee
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[0-9]+[NCV]$/,
    min: 4,
    max: 128,
  },
});

Keys.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  code: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000000000,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    min: 3,
    max: 128,
  },
});

Employees.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  empId: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[0-9]+[NCV]$/,
    min: 4,
    max: 128,
  },
});
```

Currently, I'm simply using a validation and upsert method for ease of troubleshooting and experimenting.

```
export const upsertTransaction = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'transactions.upsert',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    _id: { type: String, optional: true },
    key: { type: Number, optional: true }, // I think this is where I need to validate existing key
    employee: { type: String, optional: true }, // I think this is where I need to validate existing employee
  }).validator(),
  run(document) {
    return Transactions.upsert({ _id: document._id }, { $set: document });
  },
});
```

React form:

```
export default class TransactionEditor extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    transactionEditor({ component: this });
    setTimeout(() => { document.querySelector('[name="key"]').focus(); }, 0);
  }

  render() {
    const { trans } = this.props;
    return (<form
      ref={ form => (this.transactionEditorForm = form) }
      onSubmit={ event => event.preventDefault() }
    >
       <FormGroup>
        <ControlLabel>Key</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl
          type="number"
          name="key"
          defaultValue={ trans && trans.key }
          placeholder="1234"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <ControlLabel>Employee</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          name="employee"
          defaultValue={ trans && trans.employee }
          placeholder="12345V"
         />
      </FormGroup>
      <Button type="submit" bsStyle="success">
        { trans && trans._id ? 'Save Changes' : 'Add Transaction' }
      </Button>
    </form>);
  }
}
```

I'm using https://github.com/themeteorchef/base as a framework, for reference.

Comment: Please explain preferably with some supporting code as to what you've tried doing so far.

Comment: Clippy says: "It looks like you are trying to enforce referential integrity! Can you show the schemas for your two collections and your input form?"

Comment: I've updated my post. Pardon my ignorance. This seems like it should be something basic.

Comment: Do you want to validate in client or server?

Comment: My guess would be client side in order to immediately report validity to the user. I'm not familiar with the benefits of choosing client vs server in this case. Advisement is welcome.